# How to run selenium grid with protractor

Tags: protractor, selenium-grid2

I have set up the hub in one machine(A) by the command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub -port 4441
```

and nodes in another machine(B) by command

```
Java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/drivers/chromedriver_2.42.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role  node  -hub http://<IP of machine A>:4441/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=1 --port=1500
```

similarly i have set up other 2 nodes in other ports of machine B.And in my config file i have given the selenium address as

```
http://<IP of machine A>:4441/wd/hub
```

And in machine A ,i am running my config file by the command "protractor conf.js".Since i have given 3 browsers in multiCapabilities, the automation script will run in 3 nodes which i have set up in machine B.Is this is the correct way of running selenium grid2 with protractor? otherwise how can i trigger the hub and then to run automation script?Can anyone give a correct direction?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like the right way to me. Is there something not working that you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not a joke.
Use [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid). It will resolve your needs.